# Hacer switch toggle por medio de css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Necesito hacer este tipo de switch toggle por medio de css, si bien probé una alternativa, no me estaria saliendo como el ejemplo adjunto

[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 1):

```css
body,
html {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn {
  border: 3px solid #f0eff2;

  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 97px;
  height: 18px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #345fac;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:after {
  background: #345fac;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label {
  border-right: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label:after {
  left: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label {
  margin-left: -5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f0eff2;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label:after {
  left: -100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
  cursor: default;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label:after {
  left: 0;
}
.pesos {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 13px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.dolares {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 13px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<input
      id="toggle-on"
      class="toggle toggle-left"
      name="toggle"
      value="false"
      type="radio"
      checked
    />
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn"><p class="pesos">En Pesos</p></label>
    <input
      id="toggle-off"
      class="toggle toggle-right"
      name="toggle"
      value="true"
      type="radio"
    />
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn">
      <p class="dolares">En Dólares</p>
    </label>
```